# Probability of correctly matching all pairs

Tags: probability

I have an unusual collection of socks - they are all black, and the only factor differentiating them is that they are either left socks or right socks.

I have laundered ‘n’ pairs. If I select randomly from the laundry basket and create pairs for the sock drawer, what is the probability all socks are correctly paired with one left sock and one right sock per pair?

Edit:

One pair of socks: can’t go wrong 1/1
Two pairs: 4 socks, take one out and the chance of getting an opposite sock from those remaining in the laundry basket is 2/3
Three pairs: 6 socks. First attempt at a pair, odds are 3/5 that the second sock picked makes a pair. So the odds that all socks are paired is 3/5 x 2/3 x 1/1 = 6/15 = 3/5

Can this be reduced to a formula for n pairs of socks?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Working it out for small $n$ might be a good place to start.

Comment: Take your first sock.  It doesn't matter to us yet.  Now, when taking the second sock, what is the probability that it makes a valid pair with your first?  Repeat this process.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "*can this be reduced to a formula*"  Yes, of course.  With $n$ pairs, the numerator would be $1$ times $2$ times $3$ times... and so on.  The denominator would be $1$ times $3$ times $5$ times... and so on.  Both can be written in terms of factorials (*or doublefactorials if you prefer*)

Comment: Thanks JMoravitz, but that doesn’t work for n=2. I have a feeling double factorials is in play, and a power is somewhere in there too.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work for $n=2$?  Of course it does

Comment: Shoot me down but isn’t 2! = 2!! ?

Comment: $1\times 2 = 2!$ is indeed equal to $2 = 2!!$, but why bring that up?  For the case of $n=2$ what should be your numerator and what should be your denominator?  You already wrote it above as $\frac{2}{3}$ but you might see it easier as $\frac{2\times 1}{3\times 1}$.  The denominator here is not $2!!$... it is instead ____

Comment: It’s 2!!+1.. or (2!!)^2-1. Or (n!!)^n-(n/2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144415/discussion-between-paul-robinson-and-jmoravitz).

Comment: To explain the answer of JMoravitz, assume, for illustrative purposes, that $n = 5,$ so that there are $10$ socks.  Then, the first sock chosen can be a left sock or a right sock.  Assume that it is a left sock.  Then, there are $9$ socks left, $5$ of which are right socks.  So, the probability that the first pair of socks is one left and one right is $~\dfrac{5}{9}.~$  Now, you have $8$ socks left, and (again), at this point, it doesn't matter whether the 3rd sock is a left sock or a right sock.  ...see next comment

Comment: Whichever the 3rd sock is, left or right, there will now be $7$ socks left, $4$ of which are of the opposite side to the 3rd sock.  This explains the next factor $~\dfrac{4}{7}.~$  This pattern will continue.  This explains why, when $n=5$, the probability is $$\frac{5}{9} \times \frac{4}{7} \times  \frac{3}{5} \times  \frac{2}{3} \times  \frac{1}{1}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative approach:

This response is intended to stretch intuition by using Combinatorics to intuitively explain the answer to the probability problem.

First of all, how would you *simplify* the following expression:

$$1 \times 3 \times 5 \times \cdots \times (2n-1)? \tag1 $$

(1) can be re-expressed as

$$\frac{(2n)!}{2 \times 4 \times 6 \times \cdots \times 2n} \tag2 $$

The denominator in (2) above can be re-expressed as

$$(2\times 1) \times (2 \times 2) \times (2 \times 3) \times \cdots \times (2 \times n) = 2^n \times (n!).$$

This implies that the expression in (1) above can be re-expressed as

$$\frac{(2n)!}{2^n \times (n!)}. \tag3 $$

Now, the probability to the original problem has been expressed as

$$\frac{(n!)}{1 \times 3 \times 5 \times \cdots \times (2n-1)}.$$

Substituting the expression in (3) above, for the expression in (1) above, allows the probability to be expressed as:

$$\frac{(n!)}{1} \times \frac{1}{\frac{(2n)!}{2^n \times (n!)}}$$

$$= \frac{2^n \times (n!) \times (n!)}{(2n)!}. \tag4 $$

So, since (4) above represents an alternative expression for the probability that each pair of socks has a left and right sock, the challenge is now to $\color{red}{\text{intuitively explain}}$ the expression in (4) above.

In (4) above, the denominator represents all of the ways of **ordering** the $(2n)$ socks.

In order for the socks to pair up correctly, you need:

- [sock-1+sock-2] are [a left sock+a right sock], or vice versa.
- [sock-3+sock-4] are [a left sock+a right sock], or vice versa.
- [sock-5+sock-6] are [a left sock+a right sock], or vice versa.
- $\cdots$
- [sock-(2n-1)+sock-(2n)] are [a left sock+a right sock], or vice versa.

In the above constraints, notice that with each selection of two socks:

- It doesn't matter which of the $n$ left socks are chosen.
- It doesn't matter which of the $n$ right socks are chosen.
- It doesn't matter whether the socks chosen are [left+right] or [right+left].

So, when you are determining how many of the possible $(2n)!$ permutations of the $(2n)$ socks are satisfactory, you have that:

- There are $(n!)$ ways that the left socks can be *harmlessly* permuted.
- There are $(n!)$ ways that the right socks can be *harmlessly* permuted.
- With each of the $n$ pairs of socks, you have two choices: [left+right] or [right+left].

So, the above bullet points intuitively explain the factors in the numerator of (4) above: $(n!) \times (n!) \times 2^n.$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
n&p\\\hline
1&\frac{1}{1}\\
2&\frac{2\times 1}{3\times 1}\\
3&\frac{3\times 2\times 1}{5\times 3\times 1}\\
4&\frac{4\times 3\times 2\times 1}{7\times 5\times 3\times 1}\\
5&\frac{5\times 4\times 3\times 2\times 1}{9\times 7\times 5\times 3\times 1}\\
\vdots&\vdots\\\hline\end{array}$$

The numerator you should recognize.

> The numerator is $n!$, the product of the first $n$ integers

The denominator, given the strong hint already given in the comments you *should* recognize after having looked up what a double factorial is.

> The denominator is the product of the first $n$ *odd* integers

$~$

> The denominator is $(2n-1)!!$.  For example, for $n=2$ this would be $3!! = 3\times 1$

Could this be rephrased without double factorials?  Sure.

> To do so, we start with what we have... the product of the first several odd integers: $1\times 3\times 5\times \cdots \times (2n-1)$.  Now, multiply and divide by the product of all the even integers.  $\frac{1\times 2\times 3\times 4\times \cdots \times 2n}{2\times 4\times 6\times \cdots \times 2n}$.  Factor out a common factor of $2$ from each of the even numbers, and recognize it as $2^n\cdot n!$.  This gives the identity $(2n-1)!! = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$

Combine all of this information into a final answer.